# magento toolbar select are note ordered well

Tags: magento, select, toolbar

I have order like this `9 - 15 - 30 - 6`. 
I need `6` to be the first one

```
<label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
  <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
   <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
        <?php echo $_limit ?>
    </option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select><span class="per-page"> <?php echo $this->__('per page'); ?></span>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? im stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

Go to System -> Configuration. On the left side menu select catalog. Under the frontend tab change value of "Products per Page on Grid/List Allowed Values to wanted order: 6,9,15,30.